# How to specify delta table properties when writing a steaming spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

Let's assume I have a streaming dataframe, and I'm writing it to Databricks Delta Lake:

```
someStreamingDf.writeStream
  .format("delta")
  .outputMode("append")
  .start("targetPath")
```

and then creating a delta table out of it:

```
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE <TBL_NAME> USING DELTA LOCATION '<targetPath>'
TBLPROPERTIES ('delta.autoOptimize.optimizeWrite'=true)")
```

which fails with `AnalysisException: The specified properties do not match the existing properties at <targetPath>`.

I know I can create a table beforehand:

```
CREATE TABLE <TBL_NAME> (
  //columns
) 
USING DELTA LOCATION "< targetPath >"
TBLPROPERTIES (
  "delta.autoOptimize.optimizeWrite" = true, 
  ....
)
```

and then just write to it, but writting this SQL with all the columns and their types looks like a bit of extra/unnecessary work. So is there a way to specify these TBLPROPERTIES while writing to a delta table (for the first time) and not beforehand?

Comment: did optimizeWrite= true help improve query times for you? What's your experience with it.

Comment: Yes @OliverAngelil, it's essential for large datasets.

Comment: Thanks Andrii - I didn't find any info in the docs on what `optimizeWrite` actually does? Do you know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look into [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations/auto-optimize.html#enable-auto-optimize), you can see that you can set following property:

```py
spark.conf.set(
  "spark.databricks.delta.properties.defaults.autoOptimize.optimizeWrite", "true")
```

and then all newly created tables will have `delta.autoOptimize.optimizeWrite` set to `true`.

another approach - create table without option, and then try to do `alter table set tblprperties` (not tested although)